# How to send a message to process zero, from all other processes?

Tags: python, mpi4py

How to send a message to process zero, from all other processes?

I'm using mpi4py, with Python 2, and was following this example [Parallel programming Research](https://rabernat.github.io/research_computing/parallel-programming-with-mpi-for-python.html)

Why does this line fail, and what fixes it?

```
searchResult = comm.recv(source=tempRank)
```

My code below (appears to) works fine until it reaches the line above.  I put `print` statements above and below this line, so I pretty sure this is the problem.

My expectation was ... processor zero will receive a message from each processor, but it does not.  The program seems to just hang and do nothing.  Here is the program.

```
import time
from random import randint
from random import shuffle
from mpi4py import MPI
import sys

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_size()
name = MPI.Get_processor_name()

if rank == 0:
    starttime=time.time()
    searchResult=False
    someNumber = 0    
    data = list(range(1,8))
    chunks = [ [] for _ in range(size) ]
    for i,chunk in enumerate(data):
        chunks[i % size].append(chunk)
else:
    data=None
    chunks=None
    someNumber=None

# scatter data to all processors
data=comm.scatter(chunks,root=0)
# give another variable to each processor
someNumber = comm.bcast(someNumber,root=0)  

print('im rank=',rank,', my data=', data, ' searching for someNumber = ',someNumber)

searchResult=False
for num in data:
    if someNumber == num:
        print('found the someNumber')
        searchResult=True
        break
if searchResult == False:
    print('someNumber not found')
    searchResult=False

# Now, at this point, I want all processors (including processor 0)
# to send processor 0 a message

tempRank=rank

# attempting to send process 0 a message from all other processes
# (does/can processor 0 send itself a message?)
if rank == 0:
    print('this line prints one time, and program hangs')
    searchResult = comm.recv(source=tempRank)
    print('this line never prints, so whats wrong with previous line?')

else:
    comm.send(searchResult,dest=0)

if rank == 0:
    if searchResult == True:
        print('found the someNumber, everyone stop searching .. how to make all processes stop?')
        print('elapsedtime = {}'.format(time.time()-starttime))

    else:
        print('no one found the someNumber')
        print('elapsedtime = {}'.format(time.time()-starttime))
```

Comment: it seems like rank 0 process is waiting for a message from itself (as source parameter is 0), you would need to iterate over other ranks to get each message from each rank, or you could call comm.recv()  (with no filter) from process 0 (size - 1) times